# Detecting infeasible solutions in the Simplex method in code

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

I'm implementing the Simplex method of Linear Programming using Gaussian elimination.  However, I'm not certain how to detect infeasible solutions.  I've checked many resources, and they all give GRAPHICAL examples, which are useless in a program.

There are a plenty of questions on SE about Simplex, and I've searched through ones that seemed relevant, but couldn't find exactly my question answered.  If you find one, please refer me.

For example, here's an input tableau,

[image: Initial Simplex tableau]

and, after all the row reduction I am left with:

[image: Final tableau after row reduction]

So, specifically, when applying row reduction in the Simplex method inside a program, how should my code detect that a solution is infeasible?  What am I looking for in the final tableau?

The far left column is the objective variable P, and the top row is the objective function.

p.s. I tried embedding the pictures of the tableaus into the editor, but it just gave links.  I'm not sure how to show them, but if someone tells me, I'll update the question.

Comment: Assuming that all decision variables are positive, the feasibility of the current basic solution represented on the far right column is determined by the *nonnegativity* of the entries.

Comment: @GNU Supporter.  Thanks for fixing the pictures!  Your answer is what I thought, but I've been encountering examples that have given strange results in  SciPy and online sources, so I've been at a loss to explain them. This would be the non-negativity of every entry for each constraint, except the objective row, right?

Comment: What do mean by "strange"? "Non-negativity of every entry for each constraint": that's neither necessary nor relevant.  Here's a [concrete example](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1550423/290189) in which $A$ contains *negative* entries.  Btw, 1. Please don't use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures can't be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.  2. For some basic information about writing math see [here](/help/notation), [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) & [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).